# Update in Generic Repository with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, generics, repository

I'm having a problem in using update in my generic repository. here is the error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

here is my code, everything else works except the update.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using GameCommerce.Core.Interfaces;

namespace GameCommerce.Infrastructure
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private AppDbContext _context = new AppDbContext();
        private IDbSet<T> _entities;

        public T Get(int id)
        {
            return Entities.Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return Entities.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Entities.Where(predicate);
        }

        public T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            Entities.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {
            foreach(var entity in entities)
                Entities.Add(entity);

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            Entities.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {
            foreach(var entity in entities)
                Entities.Remove(entity);

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }


        protected IDbSet<T> Entities
        {
            get
            {
                if(_entities == null)
                {
                    _entities = _context.Set<T>();
                }
                return _entities;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All you've shown is a bland, repetitive, seen everywhere generic repository abstraction, which honestly isn't a great idea on top of a UnitOfWork pattern-based framework like EF.  What you ***haven't*** shown is the code consuming this abstraction, which is the crucial detail.

Comment: First of all, calling `_context.SaveChanges();` at each method is not good idea. Secondly, the cause of your problem is not inside repository. Where do you get entity which you want to update? May be, its PK is not set.

Comment: @AdilMammadov you were correct. i just use scaffolding to quickly check the repository and it didn't have the hiddenfor ID. thanks

Comment: I'm glad that it helped